# Forcing 2 tables to the same line in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to get to align on the same bit of HTML page.
The sum width of both tables is somewhere in the region of 1800px - which is one of the reasons for my headache.

The current state of my CSS file is as follows:

```
.inline
{
    display:inline-table;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Applying this style to both tables gets them to align - but **ONLY** when the total width of the page displaying them is larger than their sum width.

I really need to force these tables to the same line, since the information is nonsensical in any other configuration.

I've tried using:

```
<div width="2000px">[table1][table2]</div>
```

But no luck.

Ideally, table 2 (the right-most one) would resize but stay on the same line as table 1. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: why can't you have them as a single table it it doesn't make sense if it wraps?

Comment: This is clearly the easiest way to do things, but I ran into a wall because i need to apply a separate visual style to each table (and can't be bothered to stick styles on every single <td> tag in the ginormous table ^^)

Answer (score 1):

You can use white-space on the parent to force them to stay on the same line: http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/bNXPgg

```
div{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Edit: Oops, added the right link

Answer (score 0):

You could use the calc function to make one table a fixed height, and the other to fill the rest of the screen.

**Note**

this works if the tables have been given the `display: inline-block` property

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  display: inline-block;
}
#one {
  width: 400px;
  background: tomato;
}
#two {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 405px);
  width: calc(100% - 405px);
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<table id="one">
  <tr>
    <th>Header to table with fixed width</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="two">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems interesting, but I don't really get how it works, could you explain how it works? specifically this bit:
     width: -webkit-calc(100% - 405px);
     width: calc(100% - 405px);
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like using a Flexbox.  The details on how to use that can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In your case, having a single container div with the two tables as your items, setting the flex-wrap property to nowrap may accomplish what you are looking for.  In addition, flexbox is multi-platform friendly.

Comment: Tried this in Chrome, and it works beautifully. Unfortunately i'm more constrained than that, with an older version of CSS and very little upgradeability. Useful stuff though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a single table, with the content of each of your old tables in two different columns of the new one.

Have in mind that the use of tables is no longer recommended, it will be better to use divs:

```
<div style="width:1800px;">
    <div style="float:left;">..content goes here..</div>
    <div style="float:left;">..content goes here..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use style -> display:flex for main div. use style flex for table whose width is unknown, this will align table in single line(inline). http://codepen.io/saig/pen/LEwwyZ

```
    div{
      display:flex;
    }
    #fixed_width{
      width: 80%; /** fixed width table: make sure you give enough width for other table to display, though flex style take care of auto width adjustment */
    }
    #variable_width{
      -webkit-flex: 0.5;
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 0.5;
    }
```